# Meaning of and how to use ClassName<T="">

Tags: c#, generics, types

While looking at the implementation of the [Tuple class](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Tuple@cs/1305376/Tuple@cs) by Microsoft I saw many lines of code that I do not understand.

I've read all about generics in the MSDN docs, and I've never seen `T=""` and when I attempt to compile code with this syntax it fails. I would like to know what its purpose is, and if it is possible to use without Microsoft's personal C# compiler. I am also curious as to the differences in this code with `t1` and `T1`, I may be wrong but it doesn't look like it is viable code even without the strange `=""`.

Here I've pasted just one example of my question with other possibly relevant code.

```
public static class Tuple
{
    //Other Create(....) Methods

    public static Tuple<t1, t2=""> Create<t1, t2="">(T1 item1, T2 item2) 
    {
        return new Tuple<t1, t2="">(item1, item2);
    }

    //Other Create(....) Methods
}

[Serializable]
public class Tuple<t1, t2=""> : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable, ITuple
{
    private readonly T1 m_Item1;
    private readonly T2 m_Item2;
  
    public T1 Item1 { get { return m_Item1; } }
    public T2 Item2 { get { return m_Item2; } }
  
    public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) 
    {
        m_Item1 = item1;
        m_Item2 = item2;
    }

    //More Methods ....

 }
```

Comment: This is not legal C# code. I don't know why the code is written like that but it is not legal.

Comment: The fact that the compiler doesn't compile such a program tells you that the syntax is not legal C#.

Comment: The syntax highlighter just broken over there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That website is not posting the real reference source. If you want the actual refrence source go to the one [published by Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs#9124c4bea9ab0199). They recently updated their site allowing web browsing of the source making dotnetframework.org obsolete (before you had to either download the 400MB installer or use a site like the one you linked).

Answer (score 5):

That third party, non-Microsoft site is wrong. The syntax there is both illegal and nonsensical. If you'd like to see the real code, get a decompiler such as ILSpy and view the `Tuple` class for yourself.

Here's the `Tuple` code as I just decompiled it from the .NET 4.0 Framework:

```
using System;
namespace System
{
/// <summary>Provides static methods for creating tuple objects. </summary>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static class Tuple
{
    /// <summary>Creates a new 1-tuple, or singleton.</summary>
    /// <returns>A tuple whose value is (<paramref name="item1" />).</returns>
    /// <param name="item1">The value of the only component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the only component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Tuple<T1> Create<T1>(T1 item1)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1>(item1);
    }
    /// <summary>Creates a new 2-tuple, or pair.</summary>
    /// <returns>A 2-tuple whose value is (<paramref name="item1" />, <paramref name="item2" />).</returns>
    /// <param name="item1">The value of the first component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item2">The value of the second component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the first component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">The type of the second component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2);
    }
    /// <summary>Creates a new 3-tuple, or triple.</summary>
    /// <returns>A 3-tuple whose value is (<paramref name="item1" />, <paramref name="item2" />, <paramref name="item3" />).</returns>
    /// <param name="item1">The value of the first component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item2">The value of the second component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item3">The value of the third component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the first component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">The type of the second component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T3">The type of the third component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3>(item1, item2, item3);
    }
    /// <summary>Creates a new 4-tuple, or quadruple.</summary>
    /// <returns>A 4-tuple whose value is (<paramref name="item1" />, <paramref name="item2" />, <paramref name="item3" />, <paramref name="item4" />).</returns>
    /// <param name="item1">The value of the first component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item2">The value of the second component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item3">The value of the third component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item4">The value of the fourth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the first component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">The type of the second component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T3">The type of the third component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T4">The type of the fourth component of the tuple.  </typeparam>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>(item1, item2, item3, item4);
    }
    /// <summary>Creates a new 5-tuple, or quintuple.</summary>
    /// <returns>A 5-tuple whose value is (<paramref name="item1" />, <paramref name="item2" />, <paramref name="item3" />, <paramref name="item4" />, <paramref name="item5" />).</returns>
    /// <param name="item1">The value of the first component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item2">The value of the second component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item3">The value of the third component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item4">The value of the fourth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item5">The value of the fifth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the first component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">The type of the second component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T3">The type of the third component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T4">The type of the fourth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T5">The type of the fifth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5);
    }
    /// <summary>Creates a new 6-tuple, or sextuple.</summary>
    /// <returns>A 6-tuple whose value is (<paramref name="item1" />, <paramref name="item2" />, <paramref name="item3" />, <paramref name="item4" />, <paramref name="item5" />, <paramref name="item6" />).</returns>
    /// <param name="item1">The value of the first component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item2">The value of the second component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item3">The value of the third component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item4">The value of the fourth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item5">The value of the fifth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item6">The value of the sixth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the first component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">The type of the second component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T3">The type of the third component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T4">The type of the fourth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T5">The type of the fifth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T6">The type of the sixth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6);
    }
    /// <summary>Creates a new 7-tuple, or septuple.</summary>
    /// <returns>A 7-tuple whose value is (<paramref name="item1" />, <paramref name="item2" />, <paramref name="item3" />, <paramref name="item4" />, <paramref name="item5" />, <paramref name="item6" />, <paramref name="item7" />).</returns>
    /// <param name="item1">The value of the first component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item2">The value of the second component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item3">The value of the third component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item4">The value of the fourth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item5">The value of the fifth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item6">The value of the sixth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item7">The value of the seventh component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the first component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">The type of the second component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T3">The type of the third component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T4">The type of the fourth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T5">The type of the fifth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T6">The type of the sixth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T7">The type of the seventh component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6, T7 item7)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7);
    }
    /// <summary>Creates a new 8-tuple, or octuple.</summary>
    /// <returns>An 8-tuple (octuple) whose value is (<paramref name="item1" />, <paramref name="item2" />, <paramref name="item3" />, <paramref name="item4" />, <paramref name="item5" />, <paramref name="item6" />, <paramref name="item7" />, <paramref name="item8" />). </returns>
    /// <param name="item1">The value of the first component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item2">The value of the second component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item3">The value of the third component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item4">The value of the fourth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item5">The value of the fifth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item6">The value of the sixth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item7">The value of the seventh component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <param name="item8">The value of the eighth component of the tuple.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the first component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">The type of the second component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T3">The type of the third component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T4">The type of the fourth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T5">The type of the fifth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T6">The type of the sixth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T7">The type of the seventh component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T8">The type of the eighth component of the tuple.</typeparam>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3, T4 item4, T5 item5, T6 item6, T7 item7, T8 item8)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, new Tuple<T8>(item8));
    }
    internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2)
    {
        return (h1 << 5) + h1 ^ h2;
    }
    internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2, int h3)
    {
        return Tuple.CombineHashCodes(Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h1, h2), h3);
    }
    internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2, int h3, int h4)
    {
        return Tuple.CombineHashCodes(Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h1, h2), Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h3, h4));
    }
    internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2, int h3, int h4, int h5)
    {
        return Tuple.CombineHashCodes(Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h1, h2, h3, h4), h5);
    }
    internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2, int h3, int h4, int h5, int h6)
    {
        return Tuple.CombineHashCodes(Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h1, h2, h3, h4), Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h5, h6));
    }
    internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2, int h3, int h4, int h5, int h6, int h7)
    {
        return Tuple.CombineHashCodes(Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h1, h2, h3, h4), Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h5, h6, h7));
    }
    internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2, int h3, int h4, int h5, int h6, int h7, int h8)
    {
        return Tuple.CombineHashCodes(Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h1, h2, h3, h4), Tuple.CombineHashCodes(h5, h6, h7, h8));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The [reference source website](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) was updated a month or two ago allowing web browsing of the source, you don't need to use a decompiler anymore (for 4.5.1, older versions you still need to either download it or use a decompiler).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain awesome - I had no idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Here's the real source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs#6fc25ad0ccdc0f3a)

```
public static class Tuple {
    public static Tuple<T1> Create<T1>(T1 item1) {
        return new Tuple<T1>(item1);
    }

    public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2);
    }

...

[Serializable]
public class Tuple<T1, T2> : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable, ITuple {

    private readonly T1 m_Item1;
    private readonly T2 m_Item2;

    public T1 Item1 { get { return m_Item1; } }
    public T2 Item2 { get { return m_Item2; } }

    public Tuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        m_Item1 = item1;
        m_Item2 = item2;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not legal C#.

Most likely someone cooked up a "fancy" browser for the source code that runs some javascript or whatnot on the source code to produce that.

If you check the source code of the web page in question, you'll note that the code there does not have that weird syntax, so something is adding that in the browser.

It is not legal C#.

It does not mean anything.

The C# reference source does not contain those characters.